# Delay packets sent through a given TCP port

Tags: macos, networking, unix, port-forwarding

What is the best way to **purposely delay** packets (by 10 seconds for example) uploaded to a given TCP port (e.g. 1935) on the RTMP protocol?

- The approach must work on Mac OSx Yosemite.
- I have tried applications such as the [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) and [SpeedLimit](http://mschrag.github.io/) but these applications have their problems: NLC doesn't allow the specification of ports, SpeedLimit no longer works on Yosemite due to [IPFW no longer being supported](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6645172).

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux

Comment: Have  a look at netem.  Not sure if it works on OSX however.